# Analysing polygon layer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, mapping

I use QGIS.

I have two sets of data. One of them came from a brand of a combine that compiles the harvest data in a point map. I can analyse that easily using the random point selection and basic stats. But now, I have received a file from a farmer that uses different brand equipment. His yield map is made out of polygons instead of points. This is not good as one polygon might extend into two treatments (treated, untreated wheat, etc) making it impossible to collect random samples from the treatment I need to do stats on.

How can I analyse specific areas of a polygon?

Is there a way to compartmentalise the polygon with certain criteria that satisfy my requirements or is a heat map the only way?

[image]

The picture above: This is how the layer looks like. Red lines = tramlines indicating the end of every treatment( three treatments A, B, and C).When I try to select certain features, for example, the area between the two red lines, all of the polygon gets highlight meaning that the polygon overlaps treatments. I hope this image gives some more context.

Comment: You could split the polygons using the tramlines. But you would need to recalculate the polygons' attribute values in a way that makes sense given the smaller area after the split. What kind of attributes do the polygons have?

Comment: It looks like the polygons are made from a regular grid, with adjacent grid cells with similar values merged together. You could try to re-create the original gridlines and split the polygons along those lines. Use the `make grid` tool to make a grid that matches up with the corners of the polygons. If you can get a grid that's pretty close, then use the `v.snap` tool to snap it to the polygon vertices.

Comment: Colour, yield, and percent, are the three attributes the polygons have. Thank you for the suggestions. Ill work on it and post my results on here.

Comment: The colour value should be the same when you split up the polygon Is yield measured in total quantity for the entire polygon, or is it quantity per area (eg bushels per acre or kilograms per hectare)? If yield is quantity per area, then it will also be the same for the smaller polygons. Not sure about percent.

Comment: Well, a different file was containing a .json file that when I opened it in a browser, it explained what unit each attribute was in. This one does not have a .json file. So I presume that it counts in kg/ha because the yields dataset contains numbers like 9.201, 10.365, 8.051. Yes, the yield is measured in total quantity for the entire polygon. So the bigger the polygon the bigger the number.

Comment: For values that are proportional to polygon size, multiply them by (new polygon area)/(old polygon area).

Comment: Thank you so much. Ill work on it today and tomorrow and will post the results.

Comment: what if they are not proportional to polygon size?

Comment: Most values will either be proportional to polygon size or will not change when the size of the polygon changes. I can't think of any examples that don't fall into either of those two categories.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the polygon values did not change when cut

Comment: The attribute values won't change automatically when you cut them. You need to manually re-calculate the ones that should change.

Comment: using the grid tool?

Comment: using the field calculator